# Several MaxScale instances connected to one MariaDB Galera Cluster

Tags: cluster, mariadb, galera

In short, I have one MariaDB Galera Cluster consisting of 3 nodes.

I have 3 independent servers on which MaxScale running.

**Are there any disadvantages to connecting three independent MaxScale instances to a single database cluster?

Should I pay attention to something during configuration?**

I am not asking about HA for now, I mean 3 independent MaxScale instances.

I was looking for documentation but I didn't find anything specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: With the [cooperative monitoring](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-25-mariadb-monitor/#cooperative-monitoring) added in MaxScale 2.5, it is safe to use automatic failover with multiple MaxScale instances even with asynchronous replication clusters.

There should be no problems connecting multiple MaxScale instances to the same database cluster as long as it's either a Galera cluster or [the auto-failover feature](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-24-mariadb-monitor/#cluster-manipulation-operations) is not in use.

If auto-failover is in use, the node that does the promotion has to be selected by a third party to prevent multiple MaxScale instances from trying to promote a new master at the same time.